# npm hangs while extracting core-js

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I am trying to install a package that has `core-js` as dependency it freezes.

I've tried using `--verbose` but it says nothing. I've also tried reinstalling `nodejs` and `npm` completely.

Any help?